# Android video camera with TRRS external microphone recording

Tags: android, android-camera, android-audiorecord

Most android audio recording apps automatically recognize audio input when external microphone jack that is plugged in is TRRS compatible (usually one of 2 standards: CTIA and OMTP) .

[image: CTIA vs OMTP]

Search as i may, i have not come across a camera app which records video with the external microphone.  Therefore, as a last resource, I am considering eventually developing one.

Before i embark on a project which just might be a reinvention of the proverbial wheel or worse, a lead balloon:

Is there any impediment for such an app to work?

Corollary: Is there any camera app which recognizes external mic's (automatically or via setup)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This app does what you want.

Cinema FV-5: professional videography application for Android

Comment: Even works in LITE (free) version. TKS!! Attention to audio bit and sampling rates, high values may lead to AudioRecord overrun, which causes app to crash after stopping recording. If this happens, reboot your phone, open app, go into SETTINGS -> AUDIO -> CUSTOM AUDIO SETTINGS and tweak values.  I swapped to MONO, 128K, 48KHz and it's running fine WITH external mic.

Comment: beware: Cinema FV-5 app hasn't been updated since 2015

Answer (score 5):

Open Camera also allows you to choose to use an external mic. I actually had better luck with it than Cinema FV-5 as the latter still uses the old deprecated Android Camera API and shows my Nexus 5x camera upside down.  This is quite ridiculous for a premium app. So far Open Camera has been great, as it's free, open source, and has no ads.

Comment: i'll give it a try, tks!